# Pandas: Replace values in a column with 'Other' based on the count of rows corresponding to the value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe of shape (600,000 * 33)
One of the columns, lets call it, 'name', has over 2000 unique values. I have sorted the column using the below code:

```
got.groupby('name').size().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Below is a sample of each name along with the count of rows in the dataframe

```
Name       Count
John       90000
Daenerys   50000
Cersei     45000
...        ...
Hound      2000
Joffrey    1500
LittleF    1200
...        ...
```

I want to be able to look through the dataframe and replace all the names with less than 2000 rows ( <2000 for count) with 'Other', in this case, 'Joffrey' and 'LittleF'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think better is use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with filtering:

```
s = got['Name'].value_counts()
got['Name'] = np.where(got['Name'].isin(s.index[s >= 2000]), got['Name'], 'Other')
```

Or:

```
got['Name'] = np.where(got['Name'].isin(s.index[s < 2000]), 'Other', got['Name'])
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Daenerys', 'Cersei', 'Hound', 'Joffrey', 'LittleF'], 
                   'Count': [90000, 50000, 45000, 2000, 1500, 1200]})
got = pd.DataFrame({'Name':np.repeat(df['Name'].values, df['Count'])})

#check sizes
print (got.groupby('Name').size().sort_values(ascending=False))
Name
John        90000
Daenerys    50000
Cersei      45000
Hound        2000
Joffrey      1500
LittleF      1200
dtype: int64

s = got['Name'].value_counts()
got['Name'] = np.where(got['Name'].isin(s.index[s >= 2000]), got['Name'], 'Other')

#check sizes
print (got.groupby('Name').size().sort_values(ascending=False))
Name
John        90000
Daenerys    50000
Cersei      45000
Other        2700
Hound        2000
dtype: int64
```

Comment: {got['Name'] = np.where(got['Name'].isin(s.index[s < 2]),'Other', got['Name'])} this is replacing the first 2k names with other rathen than the count.

Comment: @praveen - yes, only change `2` to `2000`

Comment: i did infact use 2000 and not 2. But it looks like it is replacing the first 2000 values instead

Comment: @praveen - You are right, is necessary use change `>` to `<=`, so need `got['Name'] = np.where(got['Name'].isin(s.index[s >= 2000]), got['Name'], 'Other')`, please check edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! after changing to >= the solution worked for me! Appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using `df.loc`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["John", "Daenerys", "Cersei", "Hound", "Joffrey", "LittleF"],"Count": [90000, 50000, 45000, 2000, 1500, 1200]})
df.loc[df["Count"] < 2000, 'Name'] = "Other"
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Count      Name
0  90000      John
1  50000  Daenerys
2  45000    Cersei
3   2000     Hound
4   1500     Other
5   1200     Other
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* to use a sorted series in order to filter your data. Instead, you can use `groupby` + `transform` to efficiently create a series containing your group size by row.

```
g = got.groupby('name')['name'].transform('size')
```

Then update your series conditionally:

```
got.loc[g < 2000, 'name'] = 'Other'
```

**Example usage**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B']})

g = df.groupby('name')['name'].transform('size')
df.loc[g > 1, 'name'] = 'Other'

print(df)

    name
0  Other
1  Other
2  Other
3      C
4  Other
```

Comment: I get the following error: 
TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types